# Is the efficiency of (Qi) wireless charging affected by a metal surface?

Tags: wireless, charger, charging, inductive

I recently picked up a Galaxy S7 Edge and love it.  I've also gone "all in" on wireless charging, now owning three chargers: a third party standard charger, a third party QC 2.0 (15W) Adaptive Fast Charger, and an OEM Samsung fast charger.  The standard wireless charger is slow, and the Samsung quick charger is fast.  The third party quick charger, however, measures a healthy 720-950mA, but never fully charges the phone after eight hours overnight.

I have a replacement charger on order, but was wondering if perhaps the **surface** under the inductive wireless charger would make any difference.  The charger that fails to produce a complete charge is sitting on a large, heavy gauge steel box (safe).  My question for the EEs is, could the "ground plane" from this big steel surface cause the third party quick charger to somehow be less efficient?  Could some of the inductive energy be getting absorbed, perhaps due to eddy current losses, by the large steel surface?

Thanks!

- Dave

Comment: Simple experiment: put the phone and charger on top of a stack of magazines, books, etc. and compare the performance.

Comment: I added a comment below.  I am curious if you ever performed @alex.forencich experiment and determined the root cause of your problems.  For what it's worth, I have the Samsung Wireless Qi charger and it does poorly with Otterbox Commuter case around the phone, and that's pure plastic.  WiQiQi charger does well even with Otterbox Defender case which is VERY thick.  https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/meet-the-wiqiqi-wireless-charger-for-samsung-galaxy-s3-s4-and-note-ii  The Samsung Wireless Qi charger performs well with Samsung Wireless Earbuds, though.

Comment: Hi @JohnZabroski .  I did not test it, but instead swapped out the charger for a new one and the problem was resolved.  The current wireless charger is sitting on the same steel box and works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Your phone and the charging device form a 'magnetic circuit' across which power is transferred.  It is possible to 'short out' the magnetic circuit, particularly with steel.  In the comments, alex.forencich suggests the easiest solution:

> put the phone and charger on top of a stack of magazines, books, etc. and compare the performance

I can guarantee that the same steel plate between the phone and charger will create a magnetic short circuit and very little energy will get through to the phone, but it is difficult to determine if a piece of steel under the charger would have the same effect without knowledge of distances, thicknesses, materials, etc. that would be difficult to determine without some teardowns.

Let us know how the experiment goes!

Comment: What if the steel is made using Austenitic structures? https://www.bssa.org.uk/faq.php?id=24 Would an Austenitic structure still create a magnetic circuit? Base don the link, I think not but the idea of non-magnetic metal is completely mindblowing to me. I found this because I am curious about the feasibility of improving design of aircraft-grade aluminum mousepads with wireless Qi charging abilities, so that certain wireless mice can auto-charge and also have smooth. hard tracking surface.

Comment: Effectively, this would be a cross-over design that mashes up https://www.bestbuy.com/site/powerplay-wireless-charging-system-for-select-logitech-gaming-mice-black/6121406.p and Razer Invicta aircraft-grade aluminum gaming mouse pad.  I assume aluminum would block wireless charging, as it blocks current in general.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if the metal can be magnetized and if the metal is placed between the charger and phone. If you place an steel, the magnetic fields will attract the metal causing the some of the  magnetic fields to not travel through the receiving end.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  In my case, the charger is sitting on TOP of a steel box, with the phone resting directly on top of the charger.  I've read other StackExchange articles that talk about steel BETWEEN the charger and phone causing eddy current loses, but didn't know if a steel plate below the charger would make any difference.